# Spring JPA not initialize lazy properties even within transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mapping

*Why Spring JPA does not initialize LAZY property `MyChildEntity.myParentEntity` (all fields are null)?*

I tried to use `Hibernate.initialize` and `@Transactional`, but that doesn't help.

my service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {

    @Resource
    private MyChildEntityRepository myChildEntityRepository;

    @Resource
    private MyParentEntityRepository myParentEntityRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        MyParentEntity p = myParentEntityRepository.save(new MyParentEntity("my name"));

        myChildEntityRepository.save(new MyChildEntity(p, "first value"));
        myChildEntityRepository.save(new MyChildEntity(new MyParentEntity(1L, "another name"), "another value"));

        // At this point both MyChildEntity's are in database and have correct foreign key value
        List<MyChildEntity> result = myChildEntityRepository.findAll();
        //even this doesn't help, myParentEntity property still has all fields equals to null
        Hibernate.initialize(result.get(0).getMyParentEntity());

        MyParentEntity p2 = result.get(0).getMyParentEntity();

        //trigger proxy's method to initialize lazy field
        System.out.print(p2.getName()); // null
        System.out.println(p2.getId()); // null

        // PROBLEM: p2 has all fields equals null
        // the same for result.get(1)

        // BUT, this works correct - returns (1L, "my name") entity
        myParentEntityRepository.findAll(); 
    }
}
```

child entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyChildEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "CHILD_SEQ", name = "ChildSeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ChildSeq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_parent_entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private MyParentEntity myParentEntity;

    @Column
    private String value;

    // constructors, getters, setters...
```

parent entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyParentEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "WORKFLOW_SEQ", name = "WorkflowSeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "WorkflowSeq")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    //constructors, getters, setters...
```

Comment: Are you missing @JoinColumn?

Comment: @BhathiyaW I had the same issue with \@JoinColumn (I've updated my question). Finally I realize that was an issue of Intellij debugger, my bad

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch` attribute indicates when the related entities should be retrieved from the
database using the `javax.persistence.FetchType` enum. `FetchType.EAGER` means that the JPA
provider must retrieve the values when the entity is retrieved. On the other hand, `FetchType.LAZY`
serves as a hint to the JPA provider that it can wait and fetch the values only when the property
is first accessed (which may be never, thus saving a trip to the database). **However, JPA providers
are not required to support lazy loading, so these values may be loaded eagerly anyway.**

Source: *Professional Java for Web Applications* by *Nicholas S Williams*

edit:

I really apologize I took this long. Here is what I think is wrong. I don't see an instance of child entity in parent entity. It should look like this:

```
public class MyParentEntity {
... //other fields
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "myParentEntity")
private Set<MyChildEntity> myChildEntities = new HashSet<MyChildEntity>;
... //other fields or constructors or getters or setters 
...     
}
```

I hope this works. If not, then in your `MyChildEntity` class, there is a weird annotation inside `@JoinColumn` called `referencedColumnName`. I don't know what that is. Please remove it.

Thanks

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that I can't fetch lazy property at all. Means I can't initialize it fields through Spring JPA